# how to search and print dictionary with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

for example, I have a dictionary like this

```
print(fruitdict)
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'apple':{'red'}, 'banana':{'yellow'}, 'cinnamon':{'brown'}...
etc
```

order is not a problem, I just want to print like

```
"apple have red color."
"banana have yellow color."
"cinammon have brown color."
etc
```

I don't have any idea, because I thought just

```
x = len(fruitdict)
for n = range(0, x+1):
    print(fruitdict.keys()[n])
    print(" have ")
    print(fruitdict.item()[n])
    print(" color.")
```

of course, it didn't work.
how can I pickup the key and items in dictionary?

Comment: That is a wired representation of a dictionary , we generally have something like this : {'apple': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow' }

Comment: If each fruit only ever has one color, you may want to reconsider your design. There's not much point having a defaultdict with `set` values, when a regular dict would work.

Comment: @Kevin i think that would be long question and answer, but i'm very curious about difference between normal dict and my dict. I just make this dict by collection.defaultdict

Comment: Why, though? It seems like you went out of your way to do it. What's your motivation for using a defaultdict?

Comment: @Kevin I parse and match some page, and in my other question thread, one guy answered to me that defaultdict method. it worked clearly but I haven't been make any of dict or things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the following code

```
for fruit, colors in fruitdict.items():
    print('{} have {} color.'.format(fruit, ' '.join(colors)))
```

Comment: I would have used `colors` instead of `color` to make clear it's a collection of some sort,  but that's the only sane answer so far.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for the variable naming recommendation, you are right. Edited

Comment: what is .join? when I use none-.join code, it printed like {explain}. but when I use .join, {} is disappeared! It's miracle

Comment: @HyungsooKim The [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method concatenates all strings of a sequence and uses the string you call `join` on as the seperator. If you have more than 1 color and would like them to be seperated by commas in your resulting string you can call `", ".join(colors)`

Comment: @HyungsooKim: `str.join()` is a documented method of class `str`.  Python has a quite extensive documention (and a good tutorial too).

Answer (score 1):

If instead of a `defaultdict` you just had a normal dictionary

```
d = {'apple':'red', 'banana':'yellow', 'cinnamon':'brown'}
```

You could iterate of the `items` and use `format` to create a string

```
for (key, value) in d.items():
    print('{} have {} color.'.format(key, value))
```

Output

```
cinnamon have brown color.
apple have red color.
banana have yellow color.
```

Comment: Thank you cyber, and I have a question. "If instead of a defaultdict you just had a normal dictionary", you mean I must make a new dictionary? or is there any method to change?

Comment: How did you create the `defaultdict` in the first place? Just create a native Python dictionary instead.

Comment: in my other question thread, one guy answered to me it's good to use collection.defaultdict to my parsing data. I don't know about that, but it worked clear. so I used it.

Comment: @HyungsooKim: "programming py accident" will only take you so far - if you ever expect to come up with any useful and usable code, you have to understand what you're doing. A good read for you : http://trevan.co/dont-code-by-accident/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm noob to programming, just 8 days to learn python, so your advice is very deeply moved. thank you

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the pprint module. It will do the job with much cleaner output and
indent.

```
import pprint                                                                       
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)                                     
pp.pprint(dictobj)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
fruitdict = {'apple':{'red'}, 'banana':{'yellow'}, 'cinnamon':{'brown'}}

for key in fruitdict:
    print key + " have " + str(list(fruitdict[key])[0]) + " color."
```

Comment: `str(list(fruitdict[key])[0])`, really ? What about using `dict.items()` and string formatting instead ?